# Setting up simple configurable product for bikini sets

Tags: configurable-product

I’m setting up an online store selling swimwear. I have a number of products (bikinis) and need to allow customers to select either the set, or the top and bottom separately with different size bikini tops and bottoms.

Customers can purchase the bikini as a whole (top & bottom) and still choose separate sizes for the top and bottom. This option will be R1050. Alternatively, customers can opt to select a bikini top and not the bottom and vice-versa. With the separate option they will still be able to choose their size depending on which half they chose. The top half will have its own price (R550) and the bottom half will also have its own price (R500).

When customers make their selection (both; top only; bottom only) only the specific prices for the options they chose need to come up.

As you can see in the link I provided, (http://www.heidiklein.com/abaco-beach-eyelet-rope-padded-bkini), they have integrated exactly what I am looking for.

Are you able to help me find a solution?

Comment: Please explain a little how you want the selection to work, instead of just pointing to a link

Comment: Ok cool. Have edited my question to be more specific. Please assist if possible. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a bundled product and set the top sizes as one option and the bottom sizes as another one making them both optional.

Except for not having the 3th dropdown where the user has to specify either top, bottom or both you could pretty well match the functionality of the link you've provided. I would even think that for usability it's better to not have the first dropdown.

Comment: Will post back on here if the add on http://ecommerce.brimllc.com/grouped-options.html works for me, maybe it will assist someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at doing this as a bundle product rather than a configurable.

Out of the box, there isn't really a way either product type will do exactly what you're looking for, but I would suggest opting for a bundle product, and then creating a custom template for this product would solve your problem.

The exact setup would depend on whether you need to track inventory or not.

Comment: http://ecommerce.brimllc.com/grouped-options.html I think this is the add on that is going to help me achieve the outcome. Thanks for your feedback guys appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I use bundle product for sell separate item (top and bottom). However bundle bottom only show "as low as" price or price range. You may don't like this fuction.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your assistance so far. Its helping us get somewhere.[image: change pricing screen dump]

I need to change the R0.00 to As Low As R599 (or whatever the lowest price of my specific products are). This product is a bundled product with dynamic pricing. How can I make the As low as show on the product selection on the frontend? Any help would be appreciated.